# ifconfig wlan0 up causing kernel crash and reboots

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am testing Relatek Wi-Fi Driver in Android LOllipop. The driver is registered as

usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192du

And the lsmod shows the output as 
8192du 488167 0 - Live 0x00000000

The driver is inserted successfully . And the netcfg output shows that the wlan0 interface is down.

I tried to make the interface active as ifconfig wlan0 up and suddenly the kernel crashes and reboots after 5 seconds.

What are the reasons for the ifconfig to fail especially to crash the kernel?.....Any help would be appreciated

The kernel crash log is provided below

```
e[<8031bcf4>] (vsnprintf+0x38/0x424) from [<8004b534>] (kthread_create_on_node+0x98/0xdc)
[<8004b534>] (kthread_create_on_node+0x98/0xdc) from [<7f03d05c>] (rtw_start_drv_threads+0x20/0x5c [8192du])
[<80647c24>] (__dev_open+0xa0/0xfc) from [<80647e58>] (__dev_change_flags+0x8c/0x128)
[<80647e58>] (__dev_change_flags+0x8c/0x128) from [<80647f60>] (dev_change_flags+0x10/0x48)
[<80647f60>] (dev_change_flags+0x10/0x48) from [<806d16ac>] (devinet_ioctl+0x780/0x828)
[<806d16ac>] (devinet_ioctl+0x780/0x828) from [<806323c8>] (sock_ioctl+0x68/0x28c)
[<806323c8>] (sock_ioctl+0x68/0x28c) from [<800f09e8>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x80/0x5bc)
[<800f09e8>] (do_vfs_ioctl+0x80/0x5bc) from [<800f0f94>] (SyS_ioctl+0x70/0x78)
[<800f0f94>] (SyS_ioctl+0x70/0x78) from [<8000e0c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
Code: ba0000ee e59da014 e3a0b020 e59d1018 (e5d23000) 
---[ end trace ffb896cf8181c101 ]---
Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
```

Comment: This is not a question about *programming*. You can ask it on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about) or fill bugreport for the driver on appropriate site.

Comment: posted in Super user. Thanks for dat.

Answer (score 0):

So many reasons..... but...

1) post backtrace (kernel backtrace) for more information
2) suspect ioctl which is connect to ifconfig - bring up the wlan (if it's not ioctl, then something else like proc, netlink or whatever to communicate kernel)
3) the vap (wlan) enable code itself

I think that we may need crash backtrace and we can understand it better....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited my question and added the kernel crash log.

Comment: The carsh issue is solved. it was the kthread_run() causing the  crash in rtw_start_drv_threads.